# Debugging custom workflow activity in on-premises dynamics 365 v8.2

Tags: c#, dynamics-365

I am trying to run a custom workflow and debug it. I have copied the pdb file to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Server\bin\assembly`. I am using Dynamics Developer Toolkit to deploy these custom workflow activities. For some reason VS can't find `CrmAsyncService.pdb` to load the symbols.

Is there anything I could try doing to enable a breakpoint to be hit?

Thanks

Comment: Have you attached your debugger?

Comment: yes i have. CrmAsyncService symbols are not loaded.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how CrmAsyncService.pdb file is generated. Is it regenerated any time you deploy a custom workflow?

Comment: I should also add that my workflow library assembly is not being listed in the modules window, which is worrying.

Comment: That's the thing: I know nothing about workflow deployment. Normally the pdb is generated at build time. It must match the version of the DLL ( and preferably contains sufficient info) Often the publish build setting minimize the pdb settings; if you can control it you should set it to "full-debug", and accompany it with a debug dll. Make sure the PDB file is in the same folder as the DLL is